# Can Django admin handle millions of records?

Tags: python, django, scalability

I am wondering if Django admin can handle a huge amount of records.

Say I have a 2 million users, how the pagination will be handled for example? Will it be dead slow because every time all the records will be counted to be provided to the offset?

Note: I plan to use PostgreSQL.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

count is fast and admin pagination for objects is limited to 100 records per page. Sorting on 2 million records could take some time though, but with 2 million users you can afford some ram to put some indexes on these fields ;)

to be serious: this is no problem at all as long as your database can handle it.

Comment: To add this is more of a database design and infrastructure limitation than it is Django as it is just a display and interaction layer between the user and the data.

Comment: Performing any logical operations on this much data would be time taking in any other technology to be honest. It really comes down to the server resources at the end, how much you can provide to run the operations and how much you can afford. If any firm has that much data I hope they are making money out of it and can afford better server. :) 

In short the answer is yes django can handle it.